# Typescript detect type

Tags: typescript, types

I was wondering if there is a way to over come a ts error without adding and extra loose interface or make the id optional with the `?`

So an example would be: 
Let's say have this basic interface

```js
interface Task {
  id: string;
  label: string;
}
```

and then in the code I do this

```js
const task: Task = {
  label: "test"
}

Typescript Error here because it says that Task is missing ID.
          ↓
addTask(task);

...

const addTask = (task: Task) => {
  task.id = "1";
  ...
}
```

The error that ts outputs is

```js
Argument of type '{ label: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Task'.`
```

Is there a way to tell typescript that this is not an issue since the Id is being provided soon after?

Comment: Either make that ID optional or have a different interface, for example `PartialTask` that only has a label and later becomes `Task` when you add an ID.

Comment: By your definition of `Task`, `{ label: "test" }` is not a `Task` and the compiler tells you so. Either create it only when you have the information, create a partial "base" interface, or make it optional.

Comment: Yeah I was aware that this was the case, I really hoped a way to "overcome" this was available

Answer (score 0):

You could use a type assertion:

```
const task: Task = {
  label: "test"
} as Task
// Note the "as Task" at the end, or with different syntax:
const task: Task = <Task>{
  label: "test"
}
```

However, if the ID gets added soon after anyways, you could also just add an empty ID instead:

```
const task: Task = {
  label: "test",
  id: ""
}
```

If your code depends on the ID being unset after creating the task and before adding the ID, then you should probably make it optional with `?` and handle it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, and this is how I've solved it:

```
type NewTask = Omit<Task, 'id'>;

function addTask(newTask: NewTask): Task {

   // Do the thing, get an id variable

   return Object.assign({id}, newTask);
}
```

Typescript can't really deal with side-effects well, so it makes more sense to pass this function the incomplete version, and have it return the complete version... instead of editing the object in-place.